# How to let a new compiled ocamlc to compile a simple ocaml program?

Tags: ocaml

I build ocaml from source,first ./configure,then make world

so i have a ocamlc program under the source folder

I write a simple program a.ml:

```
let a=1
```

then ./ocamlc a.ml

but got error:Unbound mudule Pervasives

I tried to use

./ocamlc -I +compiler-libs ./stdlib/stdlib.cma a.ml

and

./ocamlc -I +compiler-libs ./compilerlibs/*.cma a.ml

but got this error too

so how to build a.ml use the new compiled ocamlc?Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually OCaml compiler is supposed to be installed by `make install` before using it.

Having said that, there is a way to use the compiler without installing it:

```
$ boot/ocamlrun ./ocamlc -nostdlib -I stdlib -c a.ml
```

- `boot/ocamlrun` is required to use the correct bytecode interpreter.  It may work without it, but it may be just by luck: the interpreter specified in your new `./ocamlc` shebang may pre-exists and may be compatible with your new compiler.
- `-nostdlib` is required not to use the standard library already installed.
- `-I stdlib` is required to load the correct standard library compiled with your new `ocamlc` compiler.

If you need to use other libraries add appropriate include and linking options.

Everything is explained in http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html , so please read it.

If you want to use compiler libraries without installing them, you have to not only link with one or several `*.cma` files under `./compilerlibs`, but also add `-I` options of directories of compiler sources: `-I parsing -I utils -I typing ...`, so that `./ocamlc` can find the required `*.cmi` files.  (If you want to play with the compiler libs, you should be familiar with how OCaml compiler finds modules first of all...)

Comment: After install ocamlc from source code by "make install" after "make world",I can use ./ocamlc a.ml under the source code floder.I don't know why.the ./ocamlc is from which I compile not I install,not the /usr/local/bin/ocaml.so why I can use ./ocamlc a.ml without error after "make install" ocaml on os,Thanks!